# How to auto Enable/Dissable Developer Options Stay awake setting as I connect/disconnect ADB?

Tags: android, adb

So I'm getting quite annoyed at always having to go into settings -> Developer options and enable the 'Stay awake' setting while I'm deving and then having to remember to go in and disable when I'm done... I'd love this to happen automatically, I have searched the play store for any apps that will do this and I have found one or two that claim to do achieve this through using a wake-lock but none of them have actually worked for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after coming up empty, I decided, I am a developer so I should just make it myself, and that is what I did.
The code is available open-source here: [ABD-Stay_Awake](https://github.com/projectdelta6/ADB-Stay-Awake#adb-stay-awake)